# Validate struts2 checkbox is checked

Tags: validation, checkbox, struts2

I would like to validate that a Struts2 checkbox is selected (boolean property) but the validation always fails at the moment. here is what I have:

```
<s:checkbox key="agreetc" fieldValue="agreedtc"
            label="I have read and agree to the terms and conditions"/>

<field name="agreetc">
    <field-validator type="fieldexpression">
        <param name="expression">agreetc == true</param>
        <message>You must agree to the terms and conditions</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>
```

The value of `agreetc` in the action is always *false* because the setter for the field never gets called. If I add a String called `test` with a getter/setter and a `s:textfield`
then that value is picked but I can't get the values from `s:radio`, `s:select` or `s:checkbox` in this action. Other actions I have been successful with `s:radio` and `s:select`.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Looks fine by me. What do you mean fails? Always true or false or something else....?

Comment: I have been looking at this a little more and it seems that Struts2 never receives any value for the checkbox at all - it is always null which will be why the validation is failing. In the action I have 'private boolean agreedtc;' with its getter and setter. The action pick up several other form field without issue but not the agreetc field.

Comment: Sorry, it is always `false`, please ignore my previous comment.

Comment: Doahh, don't post the code in comments, edit you question instead and add details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to receive value as String from `fieldValue` attribute then make your `agreedtc` variable String type not boolean. Then your validation as it is now should work.

But if you want it to be a boolean in your action class then remove the `fieldValue` attribute from `<s:checkbox>` tag and change your validation expression to:

```
<field name="agreetc">
    <field-validator type="fieldexpression">
        <param name="expression">agreetc</param>
        <message>You must agree to the terms and conditions</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>
```

Comment: This works correctly, but I also stupidly has _agreetc_ in the JSP and _agreedtc_ as the action property which didn't help! Thank you to all who commented.

Comment: @Doahh Why did you accept it if it didn't solve your problem?

Comment: Why do you feel the urge to downvote an answer if the bug was in the question ?

Comment: @AndreaLigios: I believe it is retaliation downvote... Because someone thinks I downvoted his other question, which I DIDN'T. http://stackoverflow.com/q/18270644/1700321

Comment: @Roman C I said it did fix the problem but there was also another problem that I needed to fix to be able to see that the given accepted solution was in fact the correct one. 

Aleksandr M is correct, if I only fixed the typo in the action property the validation would still fail without the solution you provided - thanks again.